# Avoid repetative column data using select query in oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I required avoid reptative data.Actually i wrote query

```
select f.fyeardescr, p.paymnthid, p.paymnthnm
  from financialyear f, mnthpll p
 where f.status = 'A' and p.fyearcd = f.fyearcd
```

data displaying data like

[image]

But i required like

[image]

How to implement the sql query in oracle.Plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use analytic function lag

```
select 
      CASE
        WHEN f.fyeardescr = lag(f.fyeardescr) over (order by f.fyeardescr)
        THEN NULL
        ELSE f.fyeardescr
      END 
                        AS fyeardescr
  , p.paymnthid
  , p.paymnthnm
  from financialyear f, mnthpll p
 where f.status = 'A' and p.fyearcd = f.fyearcd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a windowing function:

```
select case when (row_number() over (partition by fyeardescr order by paymnthid)) = 1
        then fyeardescr
        else null
       end fyeardescr
     , p.paymnthid, p.paymnthnm
  from financialyear f, mnthpll p
 where f.status = 'A' and p.fyearcd = f.fyearcd
;
```

But as tbone already pointed out: this kind of formatting is usually a task for your reporting/displaying tool/layer and not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Pentaho Reporting](http://www.pentaho.com/explore/pentaho-business-analytics/) services or Jasper reports (many others out there)  You will probably find that your report requirements will get drastically more complex than SQL formatting will handle.